# $n+1$ or more vector In V are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

## Attempt:

We are given that any $v \in V$ can be written in the form $v = \sum^n k_i v_i $ where $k_i$ are scalars. Suppose $m > n$. We know  also that n vectors are linearly independent and there are $m-n$ vectors in the list of w's that are more than the n require ones to be independent. This is a contradiction.

Therefore, $m \leq n$. Now,$m$ of the vectors in the list $(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ can be written as $(w_1,...,w_m)$ because each $w_i = \sum k_i v_i$ and the remaining $n-m$ vectors can be labeled $v_{i_1},...,v_{i_{n-m}}$ giving us our $n$ spanning vectors.

Is this argument enough? I am kind of not convinced about my explanation in the first paragraph. Can someone provide me some criticism to my argument?

Comment: For the first paragraph, you do not know that $n$ vectors are linearly independent, only that the maximum number of linearly independent vectors is $n$. The spannning set might be linearly dependent. This should be enough to see what you need to change for the first and second paragraph.

Comment: Apart from that, as long as you are careful with your choice of $v_i$'s, the proof is structually fine.